# C++ Variables Scope Question

Tags: c++, scope

I can't understand why this works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
     signed long int count = 1;

     //...

     count++;

     return 0;
}
```

And yet if I move the identifier declaration (limit) to the start of the script (just after the using namespace), it fails to compile with the error "count undeclared (first use in this function)" - highlighting the line 'count++;'.

Alternatively, [Codepad](http://codepad.org/a5dYI6c8) results in the following error:

```
In function 'int main()':
Line 16: error: reference to 'count' is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Thanks,

Will.

Comment: An I can't understand why you posted so much code that's unnecessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: Please show us what *doesn't* work, instead of what does work.

Comment: @Greg: I agree. Wasting my time checking code that works grrr :D

Comment: What you're saying is that after you move up the declarations, the compiler has no problem with curNum but breaks on count++.  I'm not buying it.

Comment: @Will Manson : Unrelated to your problem -- `signed long int` is synonymous with `long`; seeing anyone use the verbose version is strange.

Comment: @Matt Phillips : The `algorithm` header could be getting included via `iostream` on his platform, which would definitely cause an error, but not the one he showed.

Comment: @Greg Fixed that. Sorry!

Comment: @ildjam Right, nevermind, I forgot about std::count(), thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably have a collision between your `count` variable and `std::count`.
You should not use `using namespace std` as this places everything from the standard library into the global namespace and names will soon collide.

Use specific using lines such as `using std::cin;` instead.

Comment: @Shiroko Ah, OK, thanks, although 'count' is the only variable named as such in the script. I think it's something up with my compiler. That was a good tip, anyway, so thanks!

Comment: That would only happen if he included the header file `<algorithm>` that declared `std::count`.  Otherwise there shouldn't be a collision.

Comment: Depends on implementation, on my gcc-osx it seems <iostream> includes stl_algo.h. That's why some of the guys didn't succeed in recreating.

Comment: @Jason : Standard library headers can include each other, too. Apparently on his platform `iostream` includes `algorithm`, directly or indirectly.

Comment: You could also, if you don't want to constantly have to declare `std::` in front of all the STL functions just use `::count++`.  That will fetch `count` from the local namespace (i.e., your .cpp file), and avoid calling `std::count`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using ::limit, ::count, or ::curNum

This says they are declared globally. Although, you should avoid declaring any variables globally and pass by reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

This compiled and ran just fine for me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

signed long int limit;
signed long int count = 1;
signed long int curNum = 3;

// Declaration of checkprime() function
bool checkprime(signed long int x)
{
    return true;
}

int main(){
     cin >> limit;

     do{
          if(checkprime(curNum) == true){
               count++;
          }
          curNum += 2;
     } while(count < limit);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: That produced an error for me (Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2). Must be something up with my compiler. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Will Manson : It's not your compiler, it's your using directive. Shiroko's answer has it right.